# Google App Engine Error at yaml_error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Following error as shown in screen-shot,occurs when i try to run my helloworld.py script in Google App engine from terminal. 
  #My Operating system:Ubuntu.14.#
[image]

And Here is my file **app.yaml.**

```
application: #My project Id.
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1 

handlers: 
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index\.html
  secure: always 
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld_api.app
libraries:

- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

The Problem is that i can't deploy my code on local machine.
  Any helps would be Appreciated.Thanks :) 
I had check Online Yaml parser and it shows its Valid too.

Comment: do you actually have a # in the yaml in the first line?

Comment: just copy the one from here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig and replace it with yours line by line and the problem will soon be apparent

Comment: @user2266449 I had done that already, by checking an online yaml parser. Its showing its valid.

Comment: valid yaml does not equal a valid GAE yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the **libraries** line, the **endpoints** library are actually interpreted as part of the **handlers** list, which is incorrect.

Should look like this:

```
...
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld_api.app

libraries:
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Comment: i had done that too, its still showing the same error. :/